# CPU runs faster than GPU (OpenCL code)

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I wrote a code in OpenCL to find the first 5000 prime numbers. Here's that code:

```
__kernel void dataParallel(__global int* A)
{

    A[0]=2;
    A[1]=3;
    A[2]=5;
    int pnp;//pnp=probable next prime
    int pprime;//previous prime
    int i,j;
    for(i=3;i<5000;i++)
    {
        j=0;
        pprime=A[i-1];
        pnp=pprime+2;
        while((j<i) && A[j]<=sqrt((float)pnp))
        {
            if(pnp%A[j]==0)
                {
                    pnp+=2;
                    j=0;
                }
            j++;

    }
    A[i]=pnp;

    }
}
```

Then I found out the execution time of this kernel code using OpenCL profiling. Here's the code:

```
cl_event event;//link an event when launch a kernel
ret=clEnqueueTask(cmdqueue,kernel,0, NULL, &event);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event);//make sure kernel has finished
clFinish(cmdqueue);//make sure all enqueued tasks finished
//get the profiling data and calculate the kernel execution time

cl_ulong time_start, time_end;
double total_time;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
//total_time = (cl_double)(time_end - time_start)*(cl_double)(1e-06);
printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %10.5f[ms] \n",(time_end - time_start)/1000000.0);
```

I ran these codes on various devices and this is what I got:

```
Platform:Intel(R) OpenCL     
Device:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz  
OpenCl Execution time is:    3.54796[ms]   

Platform:AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing  
Device:Pitcairn (AMD FirePro W7000 GPU)  
OpenCl Execution time is:  194.18133[ms] 

Platform:AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing  
Device:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz  
OpenCl Execution time is:    3.58488[ms]

Platform:NVIDIA CUDA  
Device:Tesla C2075  
OpenCl Execution time is:  125.26886[ms]
```

But aren't GPUs supposed to be faster than CPUs? Or, is there anything wrong with my code/implementation?
Please explain this behaviour.

Comment: I think GPUs are supposed to do thier work: process graphical things (such as lots of floating point calculations) to discarge main CPU do to that work. The simple code you wrote, is faster on the faster CPU.

Comment: GPUs are only faster if you can get a lot of parallelism going, i.e. lots of threads running on lots of cores. For a single execution thread a GPU will be a waste of time.

Comment: Please read [Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs?](http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus). GPUs aren't faster than CPUs for all types of problems.

Comment: Whenever you try on GPU. First think how can you parallelize the dara computing. If you cant parallelize the arithmetic operations. Work on CPU only

Answer (score 7):

`clEnqueueTask()` So basically, you are running 1 single "thread"(work items) in the GPU. A GPU will never beat a CPU in single thread performance.

You need to convert your code, such that you divide each prime calculation to a thread and then you run 5000+ work items(ideally millions). Then, the GPU will beat the CPU simply because it will run all that in parallel and CPU can't.

In order to use multiple work items, call your kernel with `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`

Comment: But, then i'll have to change my code as it uses previous results to calculate new values.

Comment: I used `ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdqueue, kernel, 1, NULL,&global_item_size, NULL, 0, NULL,  &event);` where `global_item_size=1000` but the new timings are: 12.56104[ms], 12.56104[ms], 12.56104[ms], & 12.56104[ms]  respectively

Comment: __kernel void dataParallel(__global int* A)
{
 no=get_global_id(0); A[no]=new_prime;}

Comment: Well I can't tell you exactly what is happening in your code when you run it with 1000 global size. Because your original code is not parallelizable in the first place. But I find it weird that it takes the same amount for all the cases. Probably it is not running at all, and that is just the setup time. Check for any errors in the API.

Comment: I modified my original code and it is running as i am getting the correct output in each case

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is a sequential algorithm that relies on previous values. 
If you are running it with a global_work_size > 1, you are just performing same calculation over and over. 
The opencl implementation should compute primes less than N sequentially, then run a test in parallel for numbers [N+1; N*N] if they are divisible by any of those primes and fill in the sieve array with 0 if the number is not prime and 1 if the number is prime. 
E.g. [not my code, someone's homework, and i did not check if it really works](http://cs.indstate.edu/~jkinne/cs670-s2013/code/opencl/)

If you need more than N^2 elements, calculate a prefix sum of the sieve array (exclusive scan).AMD APP SDK contains a sample of this operation. 
This will give you offsets of the prime numbers for copying into prime number array and you'll be able to populate it:

```
__kernel scatter(uint* numbers, uint* sieve_prefix_sum, uint* sieve, uint offset,  uint* prime_numbers) 
{ 
  if (sieve[get_global_id(0)]) 
   prime_numbers[offset + sieve_prefix_sum[get_global_id(0)] = numbers[get_global_id(0)];
 }
```

This algorithm works like a tree - you compute primes up to N sequentially and then evaluate K blocks in [N+1, N*N] range, then you repeat and grow next set of branches for [N^2, N^4] etc.